# Does terraform allow us to override variables

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Does terraform provide such functionality to override variable values? Let suppose I have declared two variables given below.

```
variable "foo" {}
variable "bar" { default = "false"}
```

`foo` is mandatory and `bar` assigned with default value **false**. Is there any `resoruce` available in terraform in which I can reassign or override the `bar` value? I'm asking this in `resource` perspective. I know I could do this using `terraform-modules`.

I've tried this use `null_resource` but didn't get an expected results. It still returns the default value.

```
resource "null_resource" "this" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${var.env} > ${var.newvar}"
  }
}
```

Also I wanted to run `curl` in **command attribute**. Do I need to use an `interpreter. if so then what would be its vaule?

`interpreter = ["shell","?"]` what sete of values should I pass to execute `curl` command in `local-exec` provisioner.

**bash script**

```
function check_efs() {
curl -ls https://elasticfilesystem.us-east-1.amazonsaws.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        output=1
else:
        output=0
}

function produce_output() {
value=$(output)

jq -n \
    --arg is_efs_exist "$value" \
    '{"is_efs_exist":$is_efs_exist}'
}

check_efs
produce_output
```

Comment: Hello @muneeb - these are really 2 questions. Please put the 2nd Q (about 'curl') into its own question. Thx!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - I meant its own StackOverflow question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want. Check this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-aws-consul/blob/master/main.tf#L29 and https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-aws-consul/blob/master/main.tf#L70. Not sure you use case, but maybe it helps to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

*[Answering the 1st question about overrides...]*

There are a few ways you could tackle this. I don't know your exact use case, so your mileage may vary.

1. You could export an environment variable that has the value you'd like to use. For example, you could set the `bar` var to a new value with `export TF_VAR_bar=newvalue` and then run `terraform` in that session. Or combine them on the same line: `TF_VAR_bar=newvalue terraform apply`

   Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/environment-variables.html
2. Use an override file. E.g.:
   `override.tf` could contain `variable "bar" { default = "newvalue"}` or any other TF code. It's loaded last.

   Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html
3. Put your code into a TF module, then you could call the module and pass along the value of `bar` that you'd like. This is particularly useful if you keep re-using the same code and wanting to provision different instances of some set of resources with varying parameters.

   Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your response, the use case is that I wanted to provision an EC2 instance with a given region and mount that instance with EFS. Now the problem is, EFS is not available in some region which might cause issues while provisioning. So using some variable value as a count I wanted to determine either the EFS exists or not.

Comment: You could try something like this: `count = "${ var.efs_exists == "true" ? 1 : 0 }"`. You would set the value of `efs_exists` via some external mechanism (shell script, etc.).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I'm using `external` `data source` to execute a bash script. It's executed successfully if I simply return JSON. But if i use `curl -ls https://elasticfilesystem.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and then try to return it give me an error message that 'unable to parse the JSON'

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52789813/2613639) I've posted the whole scenario