# unable to parse JSON using terraform external data

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, curl, terraform, amazon-efs

**USE CASE**

I wanted to provision an `EFS` in a given region with an `EC2` instance and then mount that instance with `EFS`and if `EFS` doesn't exist in that region then I need to provision an alternate of `EFS`.

**PROBLEMS**

1. Amazon is not offering `EFS` service in every region.
2. There is no way to identify the availability of service using `aws-cli`. Already asked but didn't get an answer yet [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52767522/2613639)

**WHAT I TRIED**

This is the case where amazon provide the service, If I run this command `curl -ls https://elasticfilesystem.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` system returns the following output.

```
<MissingAuthenticationTokenException>
  <Message>Missing Authentication Token</Message>
</MissingAuthenticationTokenException>
```

And if I change the region to `eu-west-3` (paris) and run the command system returns nothing.

So this is the **WORKAROUND** that I've in my mind to check the availability of service in any particular region. But If i write a bash script for this and run the same command using terraform datasource `external` it shows an error message that `unable to parse a JSON error pasring '<'`. I've no clue why `bash-script` considering this returned XML, though I'm checking the `exit code` instead.

**bash script**

```
function check_efs() {
curl -ls https://elasticfilesystem.us-east-1.amazonsaws.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        output=1
else:
        output=0
}

function produce_output() {
value=$(output)

jq -n \
    --arg is_efs_exist "$value" \
    '{"is_efs_exist":$is_efs_exist}'
}

check_efs
produce_output
```

**main.tf**

```
provider external {}

data "external" "this" {
program = ["bash", "${path.module}/scripts/efschecker.sh"]
}
```